# Filtering data of all query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I create a new application with Spring and Mysql (but I am relatively free to use others things)
In this application, user logs on can not see all data (except user 'admin').
There is a tree of group, users are in group. An user can only see users (or others objects) of his group (or descendant group).

I try to find idea to do that "elegantly":
For example, if i write: productDao.findAll(), it return all product allready filtered without having rewrite all request in all DAO.

If it does not exist, I accept all kind of idea: refactoring the database? change mysql for other database, not use JPA, other.... Or may be, I'm on the wrong way and it's a bad idea to do something like that...

Comment: Where are you planning to keep these restrictions on what various users can/cannot see?  Things to look into would be using different persistence units for privledged users, or even using database options like Oracles proxy authentication described here https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/using_oracle_proxy_authenticat

Answer (score 2):

1. Use Spring Security 4. It supports Roles and Hierarchical Roles too
2. Use Spring Data JPA to create your DAOs. It integrates with Spring Security 4

Here's an example of writing a DAO using Spring Data JPA. You write the interface and SDJ creates the class for you.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.owner = ?#{principal?.username}")
    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

In reality, you'd do this in your Base Repository and extend that.

You need to create a bean extending EvaluationContextExtensionSupport for the 
 `?#{principal?.username}` security expression to work

Comment: It's nearly our current solution but I try to find a solution without rewrite all queries. For example, an annotation for entity class with your filter "e.owner = ?#{principal?.username}" **which work with complexe join too**.
(I think i try to find something impossible but i try...)